# vk api, как принимать сообщения?

Tags: python, json, vkontakte-api

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import json
import time

token = 'd...'
values = {'access_token': token, 'out': 0, 'count': 100, 'time_offset': 60}

#Прием сообщения
while True:
    r = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.get', params = values)
    q = r.json()
    print(q['response'][1]['body'])
    time.sleep(1)
```

Если написать сообщение боту, то он бесконечно его отображает. Как сделать так, чтобы бот отображал только новые сообщения по одному разу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [документации](https://vk.com/dev/messages.get) VK API:

> last_message_id   – идентификатор сообщения, полученного перед тем,
>   которое нужно вернуть последним (при условии, что после него было
>   получено не более count сообщений, иначе необходимо использовать с
>   параметром offset).

После приема сообщения записывайте в `values['last_message_id']` его ID. Точно не скажу где находится `id`, это надо вам смотреть в `q`. Так же советую пользоваться библиотекой `vk_api`, это намного проще чем работать с `requests`. Установка: `pip install vk_api`. C ней ваша задача будет решаться так:

```
import time
import vk_api


vk = vk_api.VkApi(login = "login", password = "password") #Авторизироваться как человек
#vk_api.VkApi(token = "d..." #Авторизоваться как сообщество
vk.auth()
values = {"out": 0,"count": 100, "time_offset": 60}

while True:
    response = vk.method("messages.get", values)
    if response["items"]:
        values["last_message_id"] = response["items"][0]["id"]
        print(response["items"][0]["body"])
        vk.method("messages.markAsRead", {"message_ids": values["last_message_id"]}) #если надо пометить сообщение как прочитанное
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Что будет при длительной работе без контроля, т.е при вылете? ID удалится, пойдет дубликат.

Comment: @Alban но это уже совсем другая история... Как вариант записывать ID в какой-нибудь конфигурационный файл

Comment: По моему намного проще помечать сообщение как прочитанное

Comment: @Alban `messages.get`  возвращает и прочитанные сообщения, иначе зачем вообще делать параметр `last_message_id`?  Проверить можно [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/messages.get?params[offset]=10&params[count]=1&params[filters]=0&params[v]=5.69)

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ, взяли НЕ прочитанное сообщение, обработали, отметили как прочитанное, больше ничего не надо

Comment: @Alban да, я понял, но иногда надо получить сообщение, но не отмечать его как прочитанное

Comment: В данном случае это не так, и в любой момент можно забрать `not`

Comment: @Alban так если `not` убрать то сообщения будут дублироваться

Comment: Да, затупил,в таком случаи Ваш подход лучше, но в вопросе не указано конкретно это, а подход с маркированием явно практичнее :)

Comment: @Alban согласен, намного практичнее

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, Вам нужно отмечать сообщения как прочитанные, вот пример:

```
import vk

def authSession(login, password):
    # get vk session
    Session = vk.AuthSession(app_id=1337, user_login=login, user_password=password,
                                     scope='messages')
    return vk.API(Session) 

def markMessageAsRead(message, session):
    # mark unread message as read
    return session.messages.markAsRead(message_ids=message)

def getMessages(session):
    while True:
        for msg in session.messages.get(count=4)[1:]:
            if not msg['read_state']: # get all unread messages
                do_some() # do some actions with message
                markMessageAsRead(msg['mid'], session)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    getMessages(authSession(login='', password=''))
```

То есть - проходим по всем сообщениям, смотрим на их статус (прочитанные или нет), если нет - делаем что-то и ставим статус - прочитано.

Установить библиотеку: `pip install vk`

[Документация](http://vk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) по библиотеке.